# Cannot to insert record into table Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Cannot to insert into ShopifyMonitor table record (there 2 field: id, name)
full traceback of error:

```
File "D:\Related To Python (Tutorials)\Python-Test\Working With Database\goo.py", line 174, in <module>
    c.execute(make_shopify_name, (shopify_name))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 10 supplied.
```

.

```
get_site = str(input('Enter site here: '))
url = fix_url(get_site)
shopify_name = fix_url(get_site, True)
basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
db_name = '{}/shopify.sqlite3'.format(basepath)
sql_create_projects_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ShopifyMonitor (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name text UNIQUE NOT NULL

);"""
sql_create_tasks_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    product_id text NOT NULL,
    updated_at text NOT NULL,
    title text NOT NULL,
    link_to_product text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    vendor text NOT NULL,
    sku text NOT NULL,
    quantity text NOT NULL,
    options text,
    price text NOT NULL,
    collection_id text,
    collection_updated text,
    shopify_name text NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(shopify_name) REFERENCES ShopifyMonitor(name)
);"""
make_shopify_name = '''INSERT INTO ShopifyMonitor(name) VALUES (?) '''

conn = create_connection(db_name)

if conn is not None:

    # create projects table
    create_table(conn, sql_create_projects_table)
    # create tasks table
    create_table(conn, sql_create_tasks_table)
else:
    print("Error! cannot create the database connection.")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(make_shopify_name, (shopify_name))
conn.commit()
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.add some more details.

Comment: Try `c.execute(make_shopify_name, (shopify_name,))`. Note the trailing comma, which ensures that the second argument to `c.execute` is interpreted as a tuple of length 1, rather than a single string.

Comment: make it pls as answer) and it works thanks) i need to learn a lot of things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is subtle:

```
c.execute(make_shopify_name, (shopify_name))
```

Should be:

```
c.execute(make_shopify_name, (shopify_name,))  # note comma after shopify_name
```

The second parameter passed into `execute` should be a tuple of parameters for the query - even if there's only one parameter, it still has to be a tuple.

At the moment all you have is parentheses around a variable name - the parentheses will basically be ignored by Python as they don't mean anything.

It's a common misconception that it's the parentheses that make a tuple - it's not, it's the comma:

```
x = (1)  # x is 1
x = 1,   # x is a tuple containing a single value, the integer 1
x = (1,) # as above - but the parentheses aren't actually required syntactically here
```